# file_get_contents through proxy issues

Tags: php, apache, proxy, file-get-contents

I am using file_get_contents through proxy to fetch a webpage. This setup was working fine for a good time now but since yesterday it started producing weird results.

The output of the file_get_contents function is an outdated page. If I change the proxy I get either a phpinfo page or a printed array of all the initialized variables in php, both of the server I connect to - result depending on the proxy.

Is there a caching problem in my server or a caching problem in the proxy. Is it possible that their server is responsible.

Also, accessing the page directly or through a web proxy does not suffer from the above problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proxy is most likely caching the page. file_get_contents() is a simple get source and store in memory function, it isnt cached. I know squid proxy has numerous settings for caching, but you'd have to detail your proxy setup for any further help

Comment: The strange thing is that if I use another proxy server I get the same outdated page it the same state - this is where I thought the problem is on my side.

Comment: Strange. It;s definately not the file_get_contents(). Its a simple read from this location and store in memory function. So either you have some sort of mitm caching system on your server that intercepts all network traffic (doubtful), the proxy is caching it (have you tried a completely obscure proxy? Its rare but i have seen some people configure proxy servers stupidly and it uses like a static cache which doesnt take note of who's asking for the page e.c.t. so you could be getting an old page requested by someone else using that proxy. Once again its doubtful)

Comment: or its the server thats sending the page which may have some cache control which your browser may ignore, but the proxy or your server is abiding by. To be honest, its a case of constant debugging and tracing. I couldn't give you a black and white answer without literally doing the same process myself and coming up with an answer from my own investigations

Comment: I had a problem with something similar in javascript, try to add a get data with the current time to specify the request `$sContent = file_get_contents(/* TODO put in file */"?nothingimportantforthepage=" . date("YmdHis"));`

Comment: All kinds of proxies on different hosts tested with same result 
@micha I tried your suggestion and there is no difference, I even tried fetching another page from the server and it responded with the same old copy... I will try to change the server I am connecting from and report.